# AWS Fargate container out of memory failure even if MemoryUtilized is less than MemoryReserved in container insight

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am running a single Python container on AWS Fargate with 25 GB task memory. My container is getting failed with out of memory error. Upon looking into Container insight, I came to know that max MemoryUtilized is 22305 MB only and MemoryReserved is 25600 MB. AS I can see that there is buffer memory available, still my container is getting failed. If I ran the container with 26 GB task memory, it is getting succeeded. I haven't defined the CPU and Memory on container level. Could anyone tell me why this is happening ?

My Container shouldn't be failed as there is unused memory present as per container insight.